# Is it possible to use hot reload on file saving in Visual Studio 2019 ( 16.11 ) in WPF project?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

I've update my visual studio 2019 to the latest version (16.11) and I would like to use Hot reload feature in a simple WPF application. In fact, the feature works well but it's missed the **Hot Reload On file Save** like the image below . ( source of the image : [.NET Hot Reload for desktop & mobile with Visual Studio 2022](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uBdINGe1aj0) )

[image]

However, in visual studio 2019 there is no option like this . I would like to know if there is any possibility to add it or enable it in the settings ??

The image below is from my simple application

[image]

Comment: [I'm using VS2019 and I have a Hot Reload button on my toolbar](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-the-hot-reload-feature-in-visual-studio-2019/), though it _never_ works reliably. YMMV.

Comment: This is not real time , this will make change only when fire a click event .